# Testcafe Test Script on one url then one other url without refresh between tests using setNativeDialogHandler/navigateTo

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, automated-tests, testcafe

so my particular test script, I need to run tests on 2 different urls, one, then one other. Part 1 on the original/fixture url works great, but in part 2 I have these 3 tests.

```
    test('Button Time (based on the cue point) From Brightcove', async t => { //Critical
    const dataVideoIdValue = await Selector('video-js').getAttribute('data-video-id')
    await t
        .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
        .navigateTo('https://signin.brightcove.com/?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fstudio.brightcove.com%2Fproducts%2Fvideocloud%2Fmedia%2Fvideos%2F' + dataVideoIdValue)
        .typeText('#email', '******')
        .typeText('#password', '******')
        .click('#signinButton')
    const brightcoveButtonTimeValue = Selector('.cue-point').withAttribute('data-time').getAttribute('data-time')
    const cuepoint = JSON.stringify(await brightcoveButtonTimeValue);
    const cuepoint2 = cuepoint.match(/\d+/g)
    const cuepoint3 = parseInt(cuepoint2)
    var timestamp = cuepoint3;
    var minutes = Math.floor(timestamp / 60);
    var seconds = timestamp % 60;
    var formatted = minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' + seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    console.log('\"brightcoveButtonTimeValue\":"' + formatted + '<br><br><button class=\\"accordion\\">Full Results</button><div class=\\"panel\\"><p>&lt;g class=\\"cue-point\\" data-time=\\"' + await brightcoveButtonTimeValue + '\\"&gt;</p></div>", ')
    const brightcoveButtonTime = Selector('.cue-point').withAttribute('data-time')
    await t.expect(brightcoveButtonTime.exists).ok()
});

test('BC Thumbnail Image', async t => { //Major
    const dataVideoIdValue = await Selector('video-js').getAttribute('data-video-id')
    await t
        .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
        .navigateTo('https://studio.brightcove.com/products/videocloud/media/videos/' + dataVideoIdValue)
    const brightcoveThumbnailValue = Selector('img').withAttribute('alt', 'Thumbnail').getAttribute('src')
    console.log('\"brightcoveButtonTime\":" ' + await brightcoveThumbnailValue + '<br><br><img width=\\"200\\" src=\\"' + await brightcoveThumbnailValue + '\\"/><br><br><button class=\\"accordion\\">Full Results</button><div class=\\"panel\\"><p>&lt;img src=\\"' + await brightcoveThumbnailValue + '\\"/&gt;</p></div>", ')
    const brightcoveThumbnail = Selector('img').withAttribute('alt', 'Thumbnail')
    await t.expect(brightcoveThumbnail.exists).ok()
});

test('BC Name matches IRIS page name', async t => { //Minor
    const promoVersionNameMatchCheck = (await Selector('script').withText('var promoCookie').innerText).replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/\;/g, "\;<br><br>").split('=').pop().split(';')[0].trim()
    const promoVersionNameFull = (await Selector('script').withText('var promoCookie').innerText).replace(/\"/g, "").replace(/var/g, "<br>var").replace(/\;/g, "\;<br><br>")
    const dataVideoIdValue = await Selector('video-js').getAttribute('data-video-id')
    await t
        .setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
        .navigateTo('https://studio.brightcove.com/products/videocloud/media/videos/' + dataVideoIdValue)
    const brightcoveTitleNameValue = Selector('.Definition-classic-1_11_1-1VYT-').withAttribute('data-test-name', 'video-name').child('.Definition-value-1_11_1-DlVkJ').innerText
    console.log('\"brightcoveTitleNameValueText\":"BC Name:        ' + await brightcoveTitleNameValue + '<br>IRIS page name: ' + await promoVersionNameMatchCheck + '<br><br><button class=\\"accordion\\">Full Results</button><div class=\\"panel\\"><p>&lt;div class=\\"Definition-value-1_11_1-DlVkJ\\"&gt;' + await brightcoveTitleNameValue + '&lt;/div&gt;<br><br>&lt;script&gt;<br>' + await promoVersionNameFull + '&lt;/script&gt;</p></div>"}, ')
    const brightcoveTitleName = Selector('.Definition-classic-1_11_1-1VYT-').withAttribute('data-test-name', 'video-name').child('.Definition-value-1_11_1-DlVkJ')
    await t.expect(brightcoveTitleName.exists).ok()
    await t.expect(await promoVersionNameMatchCheck).eql(await brightcoveTitleNameValue)
});
```

So these 3 tests are reloading back to the main fixture URL when I want it to stay on the new/2nd/navigateTo url instead.

I tried Test.page Method but it does not seem to work. https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/test/page.html

Any idea why that is not working or how to prevent reload between the 2 urls? I want it to https://studio.brightcove.com/products/videocloud/media/videos/**** after the first of these three tests.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to login in the first test and then continue to use your account in the second and third tests.

However, TestCafe starts every test from the page defined in fixture/test. It's expected behaviour since every separate test in TestCafe is independent from other tests. Tests do not share cookies/localStorage/url between them.

In this case, you need to take a look at [Roles Mechanism](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/advanced-guides/authentication.html). It will allow you to login once in the first test. After that, TestCafe can restore the page state in the second test.